Normal map is cut off - what is this problem called and how do i fix it? (uv map? face orientation?)
my normal map is is weirdly cut off, I'd like it to continue just to the very left an right of the sausage, it is a combination of multiple objects that I'be merged with CTRL + J.
I didn't work with blender for a while but i remember there was an easy option to fix this. everything I found on the net isnt working though. can anybody explain whats wrong and how to fix it?
the geametry is uniform so id shouldnt be  a mesh problem.
thanks in advance!




Can you provide a screenshot of your normal map?

And a screenshot of your UV map and the mesh maybe?

If you merged two objects, and this kind of thing happens, there’s a good chance the UV Maps for the two had different names, and so were not merged. Thus, your texture is only using one of them, and the mesh part that had the other one is effectively not unwrapped. You may want to undo the object merge, change the names of the UV maps to be the same in the Mesh data properties tab of the Properties editor, and then merge the objects. Another less maintenance-friendly solution is to set up two different materials for the two different parts, and configure them to use different UV maps, otherwise being identical (I mention this mostly to help explain, not as an actual suggestion: It would work but you shouldn’t use it).

what if i cannot undo the merge?

You could use geometry nodes to transfer data from one uv map to another...

can you point me to a good guide for that please?

I had a backup where they objects arent merged yet but the uv maps name is the same for all objects so what can i do now to prevent the map getting messed up?

You mention Face Orientation in the title of your question. Have you checked that after the objects were merged? - Viewport Overlays > Face Orientation. If one part is red and one blue, go into Edit mode, select All and hit Shift-N.

You can Select Linked limited by UV, and then split by selected.
